# MVC ViewModels Query with Not Exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, viewmodel

I've been searching around and can't figure out how to convert a not exists sql query to my mvc query. I thought I had to use .Any or .Contains, but they don't seem to be working. Right now my viewmodel query looks like this:

```
viewModel.Accesses = db.Accesses
                 .Include(x => x.User)
                .Where(x => x.User.Uploaded == "NO").ToList();
```

I have two tables I'm working with for this. A User table and an Access table. User table has UserName, first, last, etc. Access table has UserName, Section, UserGroup(admin, general,etc), etc. The relationship is 1 to many, as in, 1 user can be assigned to many different UserGroups, but only 1 UserGroup for each Section. The keys for the Access table are UserName and Section.

However, when they are loaded into the system, their UserGroup is set to Null for each Section, since it hasn't been assigned yet.

What I want to query is all the UserNames that have no NULL values in any of their UserGroup fields(they've been assigned all their usergroups for each section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `All` operator to make sure every member of the set has the same value. I think the following will get what you need.

```
db.User
    .Where(u => u.Accesses.All(a => a.UserGroup != null))
    .Select(u => u.UserName)
```

In your question you said you only needed the UserNames so I limited the return to just that value.